# clients.openWindow not working on iOS PWA

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am developing a Progressive Web App (PWA) that includes push notifications. I am using the clients.openWindow method to open a new window when the user interacts with a notification. However, I have encountered an issue specifically on iOS devices where the clients.openWindow function does not seem to work as expected.
Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
if (clients.openWindow) {
  return clients
    .openWindow(onNotificationAction(notification.data))
    .then((e) => console.log(e, 'e'))
    .catch((e) => console.error(e, 'e'));
}
```

notification.data is the "/messages" in this case.
it loggs null, 'e' in then method.

The code works fine on other platforms and browsers, but fails to function correctly on iOS devices.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and get clients.openWindow working correctly on iOS PWAs. Thank you in advance!

tried the full url which opens new safari tab, but want to open pwa with corresponding url.

Answer (score 0):

In Service-Worker:

```js
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (e) => {
  e.notification.close();
  e.waitUntil(
    clients
      .openWindow(e.notification.data.url)
      .then((windowClient) => (windowClient ? windowClient.focus() : null))
  );
});

self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
  const { title, text, url } = event.data.json();
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: text,
      data: {
        url: url,
      },
    })
  );
});
```

Is working for me on iOS and Chrome

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).